# What is the algorithm to convert .ino files to .hex?

Tags: compilation, arduino, arduino-uno, avr-gcc

I need to convert my Arduino code (.ino) to .hex file. **I don't want to use the IDE.** Is there a way to do this?

I'm sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: It's called compiling.

Comment: @gre_gor Can you please explain how to do that without the IDE?

Comment: you can use the IDE executable as a command-line tool ;)

Answer (score 0):

Platform IO should be the sutaible solution for your problem. You can write C++ code in Platform io which then will be converted to .hex. Also, it has provision to import Arduino project also.

Basically, Platform IO is supporting package for Atom code editor. As Atom is open source editor, you may find it easier for other microcontrollers also.

Atom       : https://atom.io/

Platform IO: http://platformio.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went through platformIO. But I feel a bit overwhelmed. Actually, I want to compile the Arduino code from Android. I don't want to use any IDEs. I came across the [Physicaloid library](https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary). But it requires the .hex file. Hope the question is clearer now!

Comment: Are you designing app from scratch for this?

Comment: Yes. But it's not exactly an IDE. Just a part of it.

Comment: You can refer ArduinoDroid app from play store. The coder stated that the app contains IDE and uploader. Also, consider the example like, you cannot compile c code without turbo c, you have to use Arduino compiler in the app.  Hope this clarifies some things.